# Rearrange string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sorting

So I have a reference field in my database with contains data like this:

```
 R8, R9, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7
```

I would like to rearrange this field to look like this:

```
R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9
```

Furthermore, there is also some other types of descriptions, like this:

```
C7 (OP1 to OP12), C10 (OP1 to OP12), C3 (IP1 to IP16), C6 (OP1 to OP12), C10, C11, C12, C45, C49, C50, C14 (OP1 to OP12), C5 (OP1 to OP12), C9 (OP1 to OP12), C15 (OP1 to OP12), C51, C52, C54, C55
```

Which should be rearranged to look like this:

```
C3 (IP1 to IP16), C5 (OP1 to OP12), C6 (OP1 to OP12), C7 (OP1 to OP12), C9 (OP1 to OP12), C10, C11, C12, C14 (OP1 to OP12), and so on...
```

Is there any way to sort it with a SQL command?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: looks like you need to normalize your database..

Comment: start by splitting your strings so your data is denormalized, http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in a single column. You are better off by changing your DB design.

Comment: I was writing a macro to do it, but I just realized that I was failing in it when I saw that there is no a pattern in the descriptions size. I suggested my boss to change the database but my boss didn't allowed me to do it and, believe or not, he ordered me to arrange it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
with cte as(select F1.id,
                   F1.data,
                   O.splitdata 
            from
            (select *,
                    cast('<X>'+replace(replace(F.data, '&', '&amp;'),', ','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter 
             from t F)F1
            cross apply
            (select fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata 
             from f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O)

select id,
       (select stuff((select ',' + rtrim(splitdata)
        from cte 
        where id = c.id 
        order by cast(substring(splitdata, patindex('%[0-9]%', splitdata), case when charindex(' ', splitdata) > 0 then charindex(' ', splitdata) - patindex('%[0-9]%', splitdata) else len(splitdata) end) as int)
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS d) dt
from cte c
group by id
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c9b1/1

Comment: @Fireblade, yes there should be one tricky ordering. Corrected.

Comment: I'm trying to run this code, but I'm getting this error message:
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
XML parsing: line 1, character 20, illegal name character
Line 24 is: "with cte as(select F1.id," Any idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Probably you have character & in your data. @IohannOro, check updates

Comment: Just checked it, I do have a '&' in my data. Is there anything that I could do to fix it? Or sort manually the ones that have '&' is the only option?

Comment: I tried, got those two messages: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1](2x13)' to data type int." "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function."

Comment: So you have much more complicated structure then you show. Can you show that row with 1](2x13?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just realized that I've it. The row is the following: "[P1](2x13), [P4](2x13), [P10](2x13), [P11](2x13), [P12](2x13), [P13](2x13), [P14](2x13), [P15](2x13), [P16](2x13), [P17](2x13), [P2](2x11), [E1-E6](2x3), [TP1-P2](2x1), [E7-E8](2x1), [E9-E10](2x1), [E11-E12](2x1), [E13-E14](2x1)"

Comment: Ohh man, this is nightmare :( probably you will have some other type of formatings. This is hell.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for you help anyway (:

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function that I created.. but I think this will help you. This was created by Andreas Goldman.

First run this query to create the function called F_ConvertStringToTable

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_ConvertStringToTable
(
@List VARCHAR(MAX), -- Separerad lista av värden
@Delimiter CHAR(1) -- Avgränsare/separator
) 
RETURNS @T TABLE (Col VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL) AS
    BEGIN
    WITH SEPARATEDTABLE (STARTVAL, STOPVAL) 
    AS 
    (
    SELECT 
    STARTVAL = CAST(1 AS BIGINT),
    STOPVAL = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    STARTVAL = STOPVAL + 1,
    STOPVAL = charindex(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, STOPVAL + 1)
    FROM SEPARATEDTABLE
    WHERE STOPVAL > 0
    )
    INSERT @t(Col)
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, STARTVAL, CASE WHEN STOPVAL > 0 THEN STOPVAL - STARTVAL ELSE 0 END)))
    FROM SEPARATEDTABLE
    WHERE STOPVAL > 0

    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN
    END
```

Then you can run the function like this.

```
select * from F_ConvertStringToTable('R8, R9, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7',',') order by col
```

The first parameter is the column and the second is the delimiter.. This will basically spit the column value into a table and then you can sort the column with a basic order by clause.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @Sean Lange there is a more efficient way of doing this. This function is actually linked to the same thread as the one above and is used in a similar fashion. Credit goes to Wayne.

Run below query to create function. This function again splits the row based on any delimiter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit
        (
        @pString    VARCHAR(7999),
        @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
        )
RETURNS TABLE
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH
      E1(N) AS ( --=== Create Ten 1's
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 --10
               ),
      E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),   --100
      E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),   --10,000
cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT N)) FROM E4)  
--===== Do the split
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS ItemNumber,
        SUBSTRING(@pString, N, CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString + @pDelimiter, N) - N) AS Item
   FROM cteTally
  WHERE N < LEN(@pString) + 2
    AND SUBSTRING(@pDelimiter + @pString, N, 1) = @pDelimiter
;
GO;
```

Then Run the function like this.

```
select item from dbo.delimitedSplit('R8, R9, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7',',') order by item
```

[This is where I got the answer](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1014298-338-1.aspx)

Comment: you should read that thread a little further. The response by Wayne utilizes another splitter which is much faster. Here is a direct link to that splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other in comments never store more than one value in a single column. Consider changing your table structure to store data, This is completely in denormalized form.

Still if you want to get the result then use this.

First you need a `Split String function`.

```
create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                         @delimiter varchar(5))
returns @split table (
  token varchar(20) not null )
as
  begin
      declare @list xml
      select @list = cast('<a>'+ replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml)
      insert into @split(token)
      select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(20)')) as data
      from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)
      return
  end
  go
```

Now you can use the function result to order the result set.

```
DECLARE @str    VARCHAR(max),
        @result VARCHAR(max)

SET @str ='R8, R9, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R10'
--set @str = 'C7 (OP1 to OP12), C10 (OP1 to OP12), C3 (IP1 to IP16), C6 (OP1 to OP12), C10, C11, C12, C45, C49, C50, C14 (OP1 to OP12), C5 (OP1 to OP12), C9 (OP1 to OP12), C15 (OP1 to OP12), C51, C52, C54, C55'
SET @result = ''

SELECT @result += token + ','
FROM   dbo.Udf_splitstring(@str, ',')
ORDER  BY Cast (Substring(token, 2, CASE
                                      WHEN Charindex('(', token) = 0 THEN Len(token)
                                      ELSE Charindex('(', token) - 2
                                    END) AS INT)

SELECT @result = LEFT(@result, Len(@result) - 1)

PRINT @result
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your have more than list. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (ID INT,ref VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (1,'R8, R9, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7'),
        (2,'A4, A7, A1, A9, A2');

WITH CTE_XML
AS
(
    SELECT  ID,CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(ref,', ','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML) ref
    FROM @yourTable
)

SELECT ID,STUFF(sorted_ref,1,1,'') sorted_ref
FROM @yourTable A
CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT  ',' + xml_ref.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
            FROM CTE_XML B
            CROSS APPLY ref.nodes('t') CA(xml_ref)
            WHERE A.ID = B.ID
            ORDER BY 1
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) CA(sorted_ref)
```

Results:

```
ID          sorted_ref
----------- ------------------------------
1           R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9
2           A1,A2,A4,A7,A9
```